# Different assigning methods of char arrays

Tags: c

Can anyone point out what's wrong with this code and why the first print case won't work but the second won't? Thanks!

```
char source[] = "hello folks";
char destination[11];
strcpy(destination, source);
for(int i = 0; source[i]; i++) {
    printf("%c" , source[i]); 
}
printf("\n");
for(int i = 0; destination[i]; i++) {
    printf("%c" , destination[i]); 
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(source));` will tell you how big the source array is. Answer: it's 12 bytes, not 11. The `destination` buffer is too small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare `destination` as an array of 11 chars, but then you use `strcpy` to copy 12 chars from `source` into it.  Every string needs to have a NUL terminator, which is part of the string, so it is important to count it when figuring out the size of an array needed to hold the string.